# Reading and Plotting from text files

Tags: matlab, file-io, plot

I have some problems in reading data from text file and plotting it.The text file contains

```
Date; Time; Temp °C
05.08.2011; 11:00:47;23.75
05.08.2011; 11:01:21;23.69
05.08.2011; 11:01:56;25.69
05.08.2011; 11:02:16;23.63
05.08.2011; 11:02:50;23.63
05.08.2011; 11:03:24;23.63
```

I want to plot the Temperature values with elapsed minutes. 
firstly i used

```
[a,b]=textread('file1.txt','%s %s','headerlines',1)
```

to read the data in a string and I get

```
'17:09:16;21.75'
```

After that I used

> > a= strread('17:08:00;21.81','%s','delimiter', ';')

to get

```
'17:08:00'
'21.81'
```

But after this I am not been able to figure out how to move forward to deal with both these strings, especially time.
I want to plot temperature with time on xaxis..but not this time the elapsed time..in this case 2 mins 37 secs.
Help needed

Thanks Aabaz.thats really a big favor..I dun why I could figure it out ..I spent so much time on it
I have some 50 files comprising this data..If i want to loop it under this code , how can accomplish it, cz i have names of the file under ROM IDs..alike 1AHJDDHUD1224.txt.
How wud pass the file names in the loop.Do I have to change the names of the files then pass them under loop.I dun knw

I have one more question that if I wanted the values to be plotted after every 60 seconds..alike as soon the data is available in text files graph is plotted , and then graph is updated after every 60 sec until some more values are available in text file

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following code. It will cycle through all .DAT files in a specific directory, read the data files, then plots with a the x-axis formatted as date/time:

```
%# get a list of files
BASE_DIR = 'C:\Users\Amro\Desktop';
files = dir( fullfile(BASE_DIR,'*.dat') );
files = {files.name};

%# read all files first
dt = cell(numel(files),1);
temps = cell(numel(files),1);
for i=1:numel(files)
    %# read data file
    fname = fullfile(BASE_DIR,files{i});
    fid = fopen(fname);
    C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f', 'delimiter',';', 'HeaderLines',1);
    fclose(fid);

    %# datetime and temperature
    dt{i} = datenum( strcat(C{1},{' '},C{2}) );
    temps{i} = C{3};
end
```

Now we can plot the data (say we had 16 files, thus layout subplots as 4-by-4)

```
figure
for i=1:16
    subplot(4,4,i), plot(dt{i}, temps{i}, '.-')
    xlabel('DateTime'), ylabel('Temp °C')
    datetick('x','HH:MM:SS')
end
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Amro..I have tried running this code but it doesnt shows any graph. I think its not reading the files properly. I gave the right path to these files but still no output. All the files are text files and what I wanted was to subplot them on one screen, meaning 16 to 17 subplots in one figure

Comment: First make sure to adjust the path and file names pattern `*.txt` to match the files you have. Then I suggest you use a cell array, and read/store all the data first. Finally you can plot them using any configuration you want...

Comment: I have one more question that if I wanted the values to be plotted after every 60 seconds..alike as soon the data is available in text files graph is plotted , and then graph is updated after every 60 sec until some more values are available in text file

Comment: @Khalid: check out this other question: [Using MATLAB to process files in real-time after every instance a file is created by a separate program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532825/using-matlab-to-process-files-in-real-time-after-every-instance-a-file-is-created)

Comment: This program talks about when new file is being  created..In my case the content of text file is modified for every 60 seconds, so i want to access the file content at least after 2 or 3 mins. So I can have my plot moving while updating values from the text file

Comment: @Khalid: the same solution could still apply: use a timer object calling a function every so minutes. You are going have to keep track of the number of lines in the file, so that the next time you read it, you would only check the new contents appended...

Comment: @Khalid: please consider accepting an answer to the original question here (you did create a separate [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561906/plotting-the-real-time-data-after-certain-specified-interval-in-matlab) for your other question)

Answer (score 2):

You can merge the time strings with `sprintf` and translate them to seconds with `datenum`. Then the rest will be easy. Here is how it could work:

```
fid=fopen('data','r');
header=fgetl(fid);
data=textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter',';');
fclose(fid);
data=data{:};
day=data(1:3:end);
hour=data(2:3:end);
temp=str2double(data(3:3:end));
time=cellfun(@(x) sprintf('%s %s',day{strcmpi(hour,x)},x),hour,'uniformoutput',0);
% timev=datevec(time,'mm.dd.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
timen=datenum(time,'mm.dd.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
seconds=timen*86400;
plot(seconds-seconds(1),temp);
```

You may want to check the date format as I did not know which format you were using, so I guessed it was `mm.dd.yyyy HH:MM:SS` (see [Matlab date specifiers](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bspgcx2-1.html#bsplnu3-2))

Comment: Thanks Aabaz.thats really a big favor..I dun why I could figure it out ..I spent so much time on it
I have some 50 files comprising this data..If i want to loop it under this code , how can accomplish it, cz i have names of the file under ROM IDs..alike 1AHJDDHUD1224.txt.
How wud pass the file names in the loop.Do I have to change the names of the files then pass them under loop.I dun knw