# plotting the real time data after certain specified interval in Matlab

Tags: matlab, real-time

I have a question that I dont know how to figure it out. I am plotting my real time data obtained from temperature sensors in MATLAB. The sensor software generates the text file for each sensor and updates it after every minute. What do I have to do if I want the plot to be updated after certain period of time; let's say after 10 or 20 values or after every 5 mins.

Comment: related question: [Using MATLAB to process files in real-time after every instance a file is created by a separate program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532825/using-matlab-to-process-files-in-real-time-after-every-instance-a-file-is-created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [timer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/timer.html).

Reusing the code of Nzbuu, it would be something like the following

```
function ReadAndUpdate
  [X,Y] = readFile(); % Read file 
  set(h, 'XData', X, 'YData', Y) % Update line data    
end
t = timer('TimerFcn',@ReadAndUpdate, 'Period', 5*60, ...
          'ExecutionMode', 'fixedDelay')
start(t)
```

Here the function is trigged infinitely but you can `stop` it or set a condition.

Comment: Thanks..it worked very fine
One more questión that I have plotted some 16 plots using subplot but the graph seems qauite small, so i wana add scroll bar..any ideas how to accomplish this scroll bar thing with some function

Comment: It's probably possible by putting your subplots in an uipanel (and the uipanel in a figure). Edit : Have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24265-scrollbar-gui-example/content/GUIexample.m.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function `readFile` that reads the data from the file. You can do the following for something quick and dirty.

```
h = plot(NaN, NaN);
while true
    [X,Y] = readFile(); % Read file
    set(h, 'XData', X, 'YData', Y) % Update line data
    pause(5*60) % Wait 5 minutes
end
```